# Fitting the training error of a neural network

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, curve-fitting

I am attempting to curve fit the training error of a neural network as a function of the number of training iterations. An example is shown in red in the image below. Here I've trained for 3000 iterations. What I'm interested in is whether I can find a function that I can fit on the first 1000 (or so) iterations to extrapolate out to 3000 iterations with some reasonable accuracy.

However, I don't know what functional form would be best for me to use. At first I tried an exponential of the form f(x)=A+B*exp(-C*x), which is shown in blue. Obviously this doesn't work too well. The exponential dies off way too fast and then basically just becomes the constant term.

Perhaps it's just difficult, since the beginning of the training shows a very sharp drop off of the error but then transitions to something much more gradual for higher iterations. But maybe someone with experience in neural network training and/or experience in fitting unknown functions might have some ideas. I've been trying various exponential forms and polynomial fits within scipy/numpy but with no success. I've varied the number of iterations used in the fit as well (including throwing out the small iteration numbers).

Any thoughts?

[image: data]

Comment: spline methods from scipy may be useful, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation)

Comment: Are your trying to predict the error curve of the training phase on the basis of the first few steps? Or are you simply trying to find a formula to describe the curve at hand? In the first case, I doubt this will work. On real problems error curves usually are not that smooth at all. Plus, the error surface is different for every set of training data and meta-parameters. And for each set of random initial weight parameters you start off in completely different regions on that surface.

Comment: @schreon : Yes, I'm trying to predict the error curve, if only approximately, based on the first few steps (where few=[1,1000] say). I'm not simply trying to describe a formula for the whole curve. I understand your argument about why this might not even be possible for neural network training, and have worried about this myself. I suppose features related to the error surface in later stages of training cannot probably be known from such features early in training.

Comment: @gammapoint how does the plot look like if the x-axis is in logarithmic scale?

Comment: @behzad.nouri , here is what is looks like if the x-axis has a log scale -- http://tinypic.com/r/2rzub0z/5.

Comment: @gammapoint sorry, "x" was a mistake, 'y-axis' in logarithmic scale?

Comment: @behzad.nouri no worries, here's the y-axis is logscale --http://i40.tinypic.com/jzk1ap.png

Comment: @gammapoint ok, this shows that the error does not have an exponential decay; with an exponential decay you would get a linear line in logarithmic y-scale. probably you may fit `1 / x^n` for some power of `n` or combinations of such terms.

Answer (score 2):

I think exponential fitting may work. In your `f(x)=A+B*exp(-C*x)`, I choose `A = 0.005`, `B = 0.045`, and `C = 1/250`, I will get,

[image]

It's just about the parameter tuning. Yet I am trying to understand the motivation that you want to fit the learning curve. I think the interpolation method includes the 'extrapolation' option that you can used to predict the error after more epochs. If you want to precisely learn the curve, you can use another neural network with linear hidden layer and output to 'learn' the curve again, though I didn't try whether it works.

Comment: The motivation for fitting the learning curve is probably somewhat unique (and perhaps for good reason). I'm trying to do an optimization procedure on the neural network inputs (how I construct my inputs/features). So I'm playing with these parameters but I'd like to be able to get an idea of what the long-term behavior of the NN training would be if I continued the run for a large number of iterations. Fully training each network during my optimization step would be expensive, and I'm trying to cut down on that cost.

Comment: Thank you gammapoint. I would suggest you select some points in your training curve, maybe only 2-3 of them , to get the rough range of A,B,C as I showed in my reply. Then the fitting may be much easier.  Use another NN to fit may be feasible too

Comment: Thanks @lennon310. I tried some fits on some smaller numbers of data points and made some progress (see: http://i42.tinypic.com/zmm5aw.png). Actually, part of my trouble with the initial fitting was that my initial guess for the value in the exponential was too large, causing problems for Scipy in fitting ). By giving a smaller value as you suggested, it fit better. Nevertheless, it's still not perfect as you can see, since the long-term behavior of my function is more linear after the exponential behavior. The function we fit is of course flat after the exponential wears off.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page: http://www.astroml.org/sklearn_tutorial/practical.html

The useful thing for your situation it describes is diagnosing whether your algorithms appear to be high bias or high variance on your data set, and offering specific directions to go in for either case.